# Docusign - make only one of two signature blocks signable

Tags: docusignapi

How do I make signatures in docusign behave like radio buttons (so that the user can only initial "Accept" or "Decline" on a form, for example, but not both?) Alternatively, we'd like to add a condition so only one signature is enabled at a time (that is, the user would have the choice of where to sign made for them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Radio button group and have conditional Signature fields on a document to accomplish your use case.

[image]

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) Call.

```
 {
   "recipients": {
     "signers": [
       { 
         "email": "SignerEmail@acme.com",
         "name": "Signer One",
         "recipientId": 1,
         "tabs": 
          {
           "signHereTabs": [
             {
               "tabLabel": "ApproveSignature",
               "documentId": "1",
               "pageNumber": "1",
               "xPosition": "159",
               "yPosition": "340",
               "conditionalParentLabel": "RadioGroup_1",
               "conditionalParentValue": "Approve",
               "tabOrder": "0",
             },
             {
               "tabLabel": "DeclineSignature",
               "documentId": "1",
               "pageNumber": "1",
               "xPosition": "360",
               "yPosition": "339",
               "conditionalParentLabel": "RadioGroup_1",
               "conditionalParentValue": "Decline",
             }
           ],
           "radioGroupTabs": [
             {
               "documentId": "1",
               "recipientId": "1",
               "groupName": "RadioGroup_1",
               "radios": [
                 {
                   "pageNumber": "1",
                   "xPosition": "119",
                   "yPosition": "199",
                   "value": "Approve",
                   "selected": "false",
                   "required": "true",
                 },
                 {
                   "pageNumber": "1",
                   "xPosition": "356",
                   "yPosition": "199",
                   "value": "Decline",
                   "selected": "false",
                   "required": "true",
                 }
               ],
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   },
   "emailSubject": "Please approve or deny my document",
   "documents": [
     {
       "documentId": "1",
       "name": "Approve or Deny",
       "fileExtension" : "pdf",
       "documentBase64": "[Intentionally Left out]"
     }
   ],
   "status": "sent"
 }
```